# Force MarshMallow to keep a Wi-Fi without Internet access

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm associating a Nexus 5x running MarshMallow 6.0 to a Wi-Fi hotspot that has no Internet access. Android keeps dropping the connection every second and then won't even try to reconnect stating that there is no Internet access.

How can I force Android to keep this Wi-Fi connection even without Internet access?

Comment: On my Nexus 5X, when I connect to hotspot with no internet access, after a few seconds I get a notification asking if I want to stay connected to it. When I answer Yes, it stays connected. If I anser no, hotspot gets disconnected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shell command works on marshmallow: 
type su to enter superuser mode.
Then type the following command: **settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0**

^^ it disables the "drop wifi if no internet connection" functionality.

Comment: This is actually a very good answer. My problem was a mistake of gateway but I'm getting the message. To disable the message, this setting is efficient. It only needs root access to be persistent across reboot.

Comment: This is perfect! Couldn't connect to my quad's wifi network consistently because Android kept handing it off despite checking the "ignore" box.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Nougat.

Comment: *Please note:* I had to manually delete the network configs and add them manually, to get the issue fixed with the command (Samsung Galaxy Tab A T585). My Galaxy S8 Android N (25) provides a solid connection out of the box.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer did you find a way to add it programmatically to the network config (as in https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) ?

Answer (score 0):

My gateway was not correct. False problem. It's true that Android offers a message as stated in the question comment by Juozas.

Answer (score -1):

To disable automatically disconnecting from a "poor" WiFi network, you will want to toggle the **Avoid poor Wi-Fi connections** setting.

This can usually be found in **Settings > Wi-Fi > [menu] > Advanced > Avoid poor Wi-Fi connections**.

Comment: "bad Wi-Fi" is certainly not a Google wording... Here https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819519#advanced, they mention "Avoid poor connections". I don't have that option on Nexus7 2013 5.1, nor on Nexus 5x 6.0. And I don't think that it would even answer my question. No Internet access is different from poor connection.