# Internet connection checking blocked by AFWall+?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, firewall

I have recently installed Android 6 on my Nexus.

I also have AFWall+ for [un]blocking selected application from accessing internet.

However, every time I connect to a wifi an exclamation mark will appear and Android will soon disconnect from it. Also a popup message asks me to disconnect because it cannot connect to internet.

However I can access internet indeed via wifi.

What process should I add to whitelist in order for Android not to disconnectme after a few minutes?

Comment: AFWall+ has nothing to do with that. It is a feature of Android. Related: [Force MarshMallow to keep a Wi-Fi without Internet access](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131132)

Comment: @Firelord considering AFWall+ requires root, are you sure one could not "accidentally" blacklist the corresponding process as well? // **OP:** Does that also happen when you disable AFWall+?

Comment: If I disable the firewall entirely no exclamation mark on wifi icon. Also I didn't understand. Are you telling me that wifi connection checker by Android OS is running as root? Makes little sense but I don't like to give root internet permission unless really necessary

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  To find which app you need to allow you can turn on firewall logs in AFWall+.  The log gives a log when traffic is blocked and shows which app was blocked.

- Enable AFWall+ (if you had it disabled temporarily)
- Settings->Preferences->Log->Enable logs
- Menu->Firewall logs->Menu->Clear log
- Disable and then enable WiFi to trigger the log
- Menu->Firewall logs

The apps involved might vary from one device to another so you should check your own log rather than assuming it's the same as mine.  I saw log entries for "root" and "com.quicince.cne.CNEService" (Qualcomm specific, and counts as part of "Android system" in AFWall+).

I have solved the problem by allowing traffic over WiFi for both the above entries.  In fact I think I probably mostly don't need root, but without root the solution was not quite as reliable to remove the error.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For my phone (running CM13) I needed to allow _Data Usage Provider_

Answer (score 0):

As the [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138533/internet-connection-checking-blocked-by-afwall#142151) and its comment show, the culprit is *Data Usage Provider*, which tries to connect to Google servers to test connectivity.

You could of course whitelist it in AFWall+, but if you'd rather not have your phone announce your IP to the mothership you need to [disable "captive portal detection"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/): as root, run in a terminal (or in `adb shell`)

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

Comment: CaptivePortalLogin, as it's called in my device, seems to be used to tunnel a bunch of other requests from other, non Android services so the command is preferable. I still have to see if this command still works on Andrond 13. Don't buy Xiaomi devices people.