# Access the network without logging into the captive portal on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, lan, captive-portal

I want to access the local network on a hotspot on my Android devie without logging in, but if i connect to it, i get the "Sign in to network" notification and the sign in site, but all my other traffic go through LTE.

Also other apps see like that I am not connected to any wifi network.

How should i force Android to use the wifi network as a "normal" wifi network (without logging in), and do not use LTE?

(Android 6.0 Cyanogenmod 13)

Comment: Doesn't temporarily turning off cellular data work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have enabled root access for ADB in developer options
2. Connect you phone to your computer via usb or open a terminal emulator on your device (skip step 3)
3. Type `adb shell` to open a shell (Assuming you have adb installed)
4. Type `su` to gain superuser permissions
5. Tyoe `settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0` to prevent the Wi-Fi from disconnecting if there is no internet connection

Source: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/148442/62445