# Cannot connect to Nikon D5300 via WiFi from Android 7.1.2+

Tags: 7.1-nougat

I have a Nikon 5300 DSLR and an Android 7.1.2 device (LineageOS).

I want to use Nikon's official [WirelessMobileUtility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikon.wu.wmau) app to browse/transfer pictures and take pictures without touching the camera.

Problem: The connection never works, even after trying dozens of times. In the manual (and YouTube tutorials) the steps are so easy (enable WiFi on the camera, connect to that WiFi from the phone, start app) yet the app never manages to connect. Many recent Play Store reviews mention this problem.

How to make the connection succeed?

**Important: This question is only for Android 7.1.2 and above**

Answer (score 0):

This procedure requires root access.

1. Install a terminal such as ConnectBot ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.connectbot/), [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot))
2. Type `su`
3. Type this command: `settings put global captive_portal_mode 0`
4. Press Enter
5. That's all, the connection should work immediately.

[image: disable captive portal mode]

<sup>*Screenshot* (click image for a larger variant)</sup>

**Explanation**: Since 7.1.2 Android has changed the way captive portals are handled, and the camera's WiFi, which does not give access to the Internet, is considered a captive portal and since it does not reply as expected the connection is gets dropped. Setting the `captive_portal_mode` variable to `0` prevents Android from doing that.

**Details**: https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-14.1/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#L8268

*(By the way, for devices with an Android version earlier than 7.1.2 the command is `settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0`)*

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does that really require root – or might the "elevated privileges" of the shell user via ADB be sufficient? I have no device with 7.x+ to test, but maybe you have?

Comment: @Izzy: I haven't tried, I just thought it was necessary after reading https://android.stackexchange.com/a/148442/501

Comment: @Nicholas I think this is somewhat related to : [WIFI connection with question mark](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75505/209414), also check the answer for other methods of resolving this issue. I would also like to believe this requires elevated priviledges..

Comment: OK, answering myself: as I suspected, it [does ***not*** require root](/a/100659/16575) (except when run in a terminal directly on the device) – the `adb shell` variant suffices. One more reference: [this answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318745). Maybe you want to integrate that with your answer, @NicolasRaoul? Also note the exact command seems to depend on the Android version, see [this XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/disable-native-captive-portal-detection-t3599789) (you already indicated that).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your test! I edited my answer.

Comment: @Izzy: I just tried with typing `su`, I get `Error while accessing settings provider
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=12592, uid=10124 requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY`. With the `su` step it works.